# prevent repeated emails via bash to overquote user

Tags: shell-script, mysql

I need some help to improve the idea/implementation.Scenario is local mini ISP. users accounts are stored in freeradius/mysql. The task is to send user email who have consumed 80% of there assigned quota.

I have configured bash script scheduled run after every 1 hour, that checks for users in mysql table who have downloaded **75%** of quota assigned to them and then ADD there username and email to a file **/tmp/overquotauser.txt** like this

```
user1 user1email@domain.com
user2 user2email@domain.com
user3 user3email@domain.com
```

When user account gets renewed, his name gets removed from the **/tmp/overquotauser.txt**

Now what I want is to send email to these users, its easy but what I want is to prevent repeated email to user every hour. Example is if a user have consumed 80%, then only one email should send to user, and not every hour.
any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Since you are storing username and email both in the text file  - you can remove the email column once the email has been sent (but keep the username in the file).   In the next invocation of the cron job, send email only to the users who have emailids mentioned.

Comment: can u give some examples plz?

Comment: @AmitKumar quota check is not for local disk. its for internet users whose data is stored in mysql table. I can check the Quota percentage of each use with the help of script, but issue is how to send email without repeating as described in the query. I have updated the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mysql table for this,since you are already working in mysql ! 
A table like this should suffice -

```
create table (
    userid varchar(100),
    useremail varchar(100),
    int mailsent default 0
);
```

Your creator job will create (or delete) rows from this table.
Your mailer will pull all rows with `mailsent` set as 0, send mail, and set `mailsent` as 1.

However, if you *really*, *really*, *really* want to use the text file - here is an approach -

1. Let's say your creator cron job's first invocation creates a file like this -

   ```
   user1,user1@example.com
   user2,user2@example.com
   user3,user3@example.com
   ```
2. Now at some time your mailer task runs , it will select the lines from this file that have emailid , mail the recipients and remove the email ids in those lines. ( You can use perl or sed for this - be careful of synchronous writing of this file from creator)
   after this operation your file will become

   ```
   user1
   user2
   user3
   ```
3. After a while your creator adds two more users user4 and user5. Your file now becomes

   ```
   user1
   user2
   user3
   user4,user4@example.com
   user5,user5@example.com
   ```
4. When the mailer task runs again, it will email only to people who have email ids specified 0 as in step 2.

There are multiple ways for this schema to work.

Comment: Thank you,
Finally I managed to sort it :)
I create extra colum with name of qmail with value of 0 and 1
and the script modify it accordingly and mailer checks for this flag :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one of following two approaches.

I) Every one hour create a file **/tmp/overquotausernew.txt** and compare this file with old file **/tmp/overquotausernew.txt**.
If any new users are found in newly created file, then send email to only those users and merge newly created file with **/tmp/overquotauser.txt**

In this way, you will maintain only one file with all usernames to which email is sent. And script will chk for any new users to which mail is not sent.

II) You can create a script to send mail such that it will check if mail to particular user from **/tmp/overquotauser.txt** is sent or not within last 24 hrs.
If mail is sent in last 24 hrs then script will do nothing else it will send mail to that user.

Comment: Any examples please?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use built-in `quota` tools of *nix systems... as from [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/).

If `Soft Limit` is `800MB` and `Hard Limit` is `1000MB` then user will be emailed when `Soft Limit` is reached, allowing user to still create files until `Hard Limit` is reached.

:)